# Can't install openntpd: "unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?" "pre-installation script returned error exit status 1"

Tags: debian, dpkg, ntp, deb

I'm trying to install openntpd (`sudo apt-get install openntpd`) and I'm getting:

```
Preparing to unpack .../openntpd_1%3a6.0p1-2_amd64.deb ...
Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?
Use --subdomainfs to override.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archive/openntpd_%3a6.0p1-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archive/openntpd_%3a6.0p1-2_amd64.deb
```

I already tried rebooting and:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archive/openntpd_%3a6.0p1-2_amd64.deb
```

I also examined `/var/lib/dpkg/info/openntpd.preinst`.

I can install other packages. Is it a bug in openntpd? That would be strange because I have the latest version running on another of my Debian 9 KDE machines. All of these are using the `4.9.0-8-amd64` kernel. Maybe it has something to do with AppArmor?

Why am I getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: You should [edit] the question to tell potential answerers what the kernel versions are on both the functional and nonfunctional machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after running `sudo apt-get purge ntp`.

Comment: Now it work without any problem , no additional action required.

Answer (score 1):

The package is buggy . You can install it from [backports](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/openntpd).

```
apt install -t stretch-backports openntpd
```

You can report a bug to debian : [How to report a bug in Debian using reportbug](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting).

[Debian Backports](https://backports.debian.org/)